# Docker container cant install synApps or Debian

Tags: linux, docker, debian, containers

I am trying to create a Debian and synApps container with a dockerfile but i cant even create the image without getting this error:

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./synapps5_8.sh && rm synapps5_8.sh]: exit code: 2
```

similar containers for other softwares displayed similar errors. Im new to using docker and containers so i might be doing something wrong, but i dont know. Is some dependency missing from my system?

Here is the full message:

```
#11 362.3 /usr/bin/g++  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE            -D_X86_64_  -DUNIX  -Dlinux     -O3 -g   -Wall      -mtune=generic     -
#11 362.3 [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]
#11 374.9 ../../../ADApp/netCDFSrc/libdispatch/var1.c: In function 'NCDEFAULT_put_varm':
#11 374.9 ../../../ADApp/netCDFSrc/libdispatch/var1.c:611:7: warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
#11 374.9        if(stride != NULL)
#11 374.9        ^~
#11 374.9 ../../../ADApp/netCDFSrc/libdispatch/var1.c:613:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the 'if'
#11 374.9    for (idim = 0; idim <= maxidim; ++idim)
#11 374.9    ^~~
#11 377.5 In file included from ../napi.c:391:0:
#11 377.5 ../napi5.h:6:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
#11 377.5  #include <hdf5.h>
#11 377.5                   ^
#11 377.5 compilation terminated.
#11 377.5 make[5]: *** [napi.o] Error 1
#11 377.5 make[4]: *** [install.linux-x86_64] Error 2
#11 377.5 make[3]: *** [nexusSrc.install] Error 2
#11 377.5 make[2]: *** [ADApp.install] Error 2
#11 377.5 make[1]: *** [/usr/local/epics/synApps_5_8/support/areaDetector-R2-0/ADCore-R2-2.install] Error 2
#11 377.5 make: *** [/usr/local/epics/synApps_5_8/support/areaDetector-R2-0.install] Error 2
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./synapps5_8.sh && rm synapps5_8.sh]: exit code: 2
```

Comment: First of all you need to provide is with your Dockerfile so that we can know what it is exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: If you're missing a -dev package to provide that header file, you can search by file name on https://packages.debian.org/.